# SSIS calculate sum of one column in flat file

Tags: ssis

I have one flat file i made connection using `flat file source editor`
when I did preview i got following output.
I want to do sum of `column 5` and stored that values into sql database table
help me.
   [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Aggregate Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms138031.aspx) to sum those values. The reason you only see Group By, Count, Count Distinct is because you are attempting to perform operations on a string column.  Compare the available aggregations for text to numeric column

### String data type

[image: Aggregate options for string]

### Numeric data type

[image: Aggregate options for numeric data type]

How do you fix your package? Your Connection Manager appears to have a header row with column names in it, make that change in the CM itself. While you are in there, update the definition of A-AST-NV as a decimal or floating point value so that you can perform numeric operations on it.

The other option is to leave it as string and as a precedence task, use a [Data Conversion Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141706.aspx) to make it so.

Comment: In the `operation` no option for  `sum` only have `group by` , `count` and `count distinct` ??

Comment: Expanded answer to address the further issues you are encountering

Comment: as i have posted my screenshot [column 5] header is string and all rows are numeric and i want sum of all and want to take that output and insert into table using ssis pleae help

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem where SUM was not available even though the datatype of the column should have been MONEY. What happened was that the stored proc that returned that column returned it like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (AgencyPayment <> 0) THEN AgencyPayment ELSE AgencyAdjustment   END        AS TransactionAmount
```

Even though both AgencyPayment and AgencyAdjustment are of type MONEY, the case statement was outputting a string (or SSIS interpreted it that way).